# How to sum cells in Google Sheets that contain numbers and text?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This has already been [addressed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03) in Excel but I was wondering how to do the same in Google Sheets.

So suppose the B cell has this formula:

```
="frontend (days)
total: "&sum(B2,B10,B14,B20)
```

and the C cell has a similar formula. I would like the D cell to add the numbers in those two cells.

[image: WA92983 Q example]

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"\d+\.?\d+$|\d+")*1+REGEXEXTRACT(C1,"\d+\.?\d+$|\d+")*1
```

`REGEXEXTRACT` part of formula "\d+.?\d+$" does this:

- `\d` - match and retun digit from 0 to 9
- `\d+` - gives one or more digits
- `.` - any symbol
- `\.` - dot
- `?` - makes previous symbol optional (we use it here to match integers)
- `$` - matches end of string
- `|` - OR

---

**Update 2016/09**

In some cases you may need to use different regular expressions and formulas. For example, if we have the text `total = $1,734.00` and want to get 1734, we need this formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(F1,"[^\d]","")/100
```

this formula does the following:

- replace all symbols except digits
- divide by 100 because we get number 173400 in first operation

Comment: Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "\d+.\d+$" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "frontend (days) total: 6".

Comment: Also, an explanation of what the formula/regexes actually _does_ would be useful, especially for other readers that are trying to do something similar. For example, see the "Explained" section of [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49831/21583), in which the different parts of a formula is detailed.

Comment: btw @MaxMakhrov your code breaks if the the numbers you are summing (ie the contents of `B1`/`C1` etc) are less than 2 digits long.. can you please fix it?

Comment: hey @MaxMakhrov your code doesn't match a number like this `$1,734.00` please update

Comment: You may try experimenting with different formulas and expressions. I've updated the answer, so it matches more examples.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov: I think that you will find helpful the following Q&A from [meta.se] -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/289691

Comment: @Rubén man you got your eyes like a hawk on my posts.. and across different stackexchange sites as well eh? I'll take that as a compliment.. thanks man :)

Comment: @abbood: I'm looking for Google Sheets and Google Apps Scripts questions on [so], [webapps.se], [es.so] and on few of other places out of [se] If you found one interesting, please ping me on the [se] chat :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should meet your requirement:

```
=sum(B2,B10,B14,B20,C2,C10,C14,C20)
```

*provided* the cell it is in is [formatted](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) something like:

```
"total: "##.#
```

However you have accepted an A that does not display `total:` and that could be achieved with formatting instead such as:

```
##.#
```

Answer (score -1):

D = sum(B2,B10,B14,B20) + sum(c2,c10,c14,c20)

Comment: the whole point of the question is to avoid this redundancy

Comment: So you implement something with considerably more complexity, so avoid a little redundancy?    It's an interesting trade off, but I know which option I see as easier to create and maintain.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ You should not judge the complexity of a script against manual work based on the minimal example used in the question. Minimal examples should only illustrate the principle, not the scale of the problem.
Maybe the author (or somebody else here) needs to process thousands of cells with different formulas, which can be processed with a single regular expression..